# Copy Visual Studio Project - Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 project inside a Visual Studio 2015 solution. I needed an exact copy of the project so in the File Explorer I copied the project and pasted to create a new project.

I renamed the copied project so that both projects now have a different name. I also updated the Namespaces inside of any classes in the copied project to reflect the new project name.

```
MyProjects.ProjectOne
MyProjects.ProjectTwo
```

I also deleted the Bin directory in the newly copied project. Both projects are targeted at the .Net Framework 4.0. I've restarted Visual Studio, but I still get the following compilation error when I now try to run either Project:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ProjectOne' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProjects' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I'm running out of ideas with regards to solving this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the project which you copied has the correct references, and that the versions of the assemblies are the same as on the old project. You can also use the Object Browser to inspect an assembly and verify whether it contains the types that you expect it to contain.

For more information, see Troubleshooting [.NET Framework Targeting Errors.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/troubleshooting-dotnet-framework-targeting-errors)